# How to save .mat files of multiple files with their respective name

Tags: matlab

```
filename = ((fname{ind}) ,'.mat');
save((fname(ind)),'*.mat');
```

where 'ind' is index of file name.I want to store result of each .wav file from workspace into .mat with respective .wav file name.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  This obviously requires more context.  Please show us what you're doing with the WAV files.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you are going to store a series of names in an array and then want to go down that array as you go through corresponding variables (based on your `fname{ind}`, then `filename = [fname{ind},'.mat']` should be the only fix you need for the filename assignment (notice changing the parenthesis to brackets). As for the `save` line, if you don't specify the specific variables, everything in the workspace will be saved. More context is needed for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save('something.mat') alone will save all your workspace together in the .mat file. To do what (I think) you want you must loop through "ind" and edit your saving command:

```
for ind = 1:X
filename = [fname{ind} '.mat']
save(filename,[fname{ind} '.wav']);
end
```